# Ошибка проверки задачи на сайте e-olimp

Tags: c++

Входные данные

В каждой строке задано два целых числа A и B (|A|, |B| ≤ 30000). Считывайте данные до конца файла.

Выходные данные

Для каждого приведенного примера выведите сумму A + B в отдельной строке.

1 1 | 2

На компьютере вроде все ок, но система не признает мое решение. В чем проблема? Вот код мой:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int a; int b; int c;
cin >> a >> b;    
c=a+b;
cout << c << endl;

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: 1. Данные считываются не из файла, а с клавиатуры, и выводятся на экран.

2. Что значит "Система не признает?"

Comment: т.е компилятор сайта не признает, что-то не то

Comment: EXIT_SUCCESS находится в хедере cstdlib. Пиши просто return 0. Хотя все равно все неправильно.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.e-olimp.com/problems/1000 ?

У вас на входе **несколько** строк, причём **в файле**. Просто ваша программа обрабатывает одну строку и выходит, а нужно чтобы она сначала собирала все данные а потом выводила по одной строке на каждую строку входных данных. Это во первых. Во вторых у вас должно быть считывание из файла, а не со стандартного ввода. [Тут есть](http://www.e-olimp.com/articles/how-to-draw-solution-c) код того как это организовывается.

Comment: да! эта задача

Comment: но я ничего не понял с того что он считывает из файла. Откуда можно про них подробно прочитать?

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <iostream.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int a, b,,c;
cin >> a >> b;    
c=a+b;
cout << c << endl;

return 0;
}
```